# How to call Graphql API using GET Method in Magento 2?

Tags: api, magento2.3.4, magento-graphql

On official Magento dev docs mentioned that we can use the Graphql API using GET & POST methods.

Reference Link : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/send-request.html?itm_source=merchdocs&itm_medium=search_page&itm_campaign=federated_search&itm_term=price%20rules

As I have set up PWA studio in localhost & found that the frontend loads the Home page & PLP page by calling Graphql GET APIs. Please check the below screenshot for the same.

[image]

How to call the below POST query method using GET method ?

```
{
  storeConfig {
    id
    code
    website_id
    locale
    base_currency_code
    default_display_currency_code
    timezone
    weight_unit
    base_url
    base_link_url
    base_static_url
    base_media_url
    secure_base_url
    secure_base_link_url
    secure_base_static_url
    secure_base_media_url
    store_name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **You need to change your method post to get. You can check the below image.**

[image]

Comment: I am not able to find the method change option in the chromeiQL extension. Which extension you are using for GraphQL API?

Comment: @JitendraPatel I used Altair GraphQL Client https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/altair-graphql-client/flnheeellpciglgpaodhkhmapeljopja?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL is a big mess in Magento, it actually does not return the same results as calling the internal calls directly, creating your own GraphQL endpoints is even worse asthere is an exact definition required such as in the schema, one character wrong and it fails but does not tell you why.

As already mentioned you need to change the post to get as the correct method call, we had to develop our own GraphQL queries/mutations to replace the Magento internal ones because the Magento get results were wrong (we had 15,000 products and they probably only tested it on 100s of products), at which point we moved back to internal calls, it was for automated data loading which required delta checks on Magento from the Product Manager.

Be very sure you really want GraphQL, it can take 10x longer to create and maintain than rest or internal calls.